# Cevelop objects to un-initialized variable char junk

Tags: c++, cevelop

[Cevelop](https://www.cevelop.com/) objects to `char junk` as an "un-initialized variable". What is the correct way to address the issue in this case?

[image]

```
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os_a, College& college_a) {
   return os_a <<  college_a.id_ + ' ' + college_a.name_;
 }

 friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is_a, College& college_a) {
   char junk;
   return is_a >> college_a.id_ >> std::noskipws
       >> junk, std::getline(is_a, college_a.name_);  // name: between 1st space and endofline.
  }
```

Comment: Looks like a false positive in the diagnostic engine.

Comment: As Baum mit Augen mentioned, it might be a mistake to complain about an uninitialised variable which does not need it for being written before used. Your objective is probably to get rid of the warning in an efficient way. For that just initialising the variable seems the most obvious solution, even without community confirmation that it is a false positive. Please explain why this is not an option for you.

Comment: Is there meant to be a *comma* after `>> junk`? Shouldn't that be a *semicolon*?

Comment: @Galik Unlikely, the code after the semicolon would not be executed.

Comment: @Galik Then the `getline` would never be called. The comma is correct. (Although the code is needlessly clever, of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices, you can initialize `junk` to something or you can just get rid of it.  Since you know you need to eat just a space you and use `get` like

```
return is_a >> college_a.id_, is_a.get(), std::getline(is_a,college_a.name_);
```

and it will do the same thing.  You can also make the code a little easier to read with

```
is_a >> college_a.id_;
is_a.get();
std::getline(is_a,college_a.name_);
return is_a;
```

Comment: Not only removed un-initialize, unneeded variable but made the std::noskipws spurious.

Comment: Which now reads to me as "Read  ID, eat a space, read rest of line for NAME". Much clearer. The end of line comment then becomes unneeded, also.

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII I try to make my code as expressive as possible to cut down on comments.